# python 3 smtplib sendmail/send_message(mail_options=[], rcpt_options=[])

Tags: python, smtplib

The docs specify that you can include `mail_options=[]`, `rcpt_options=[]` as parameters for `sendmail` or `send_message`. I have not been able to find anywhere exactly what those options are. I am assuming that somewhere in there is where I can set DSN among others. I already have an email script built that works well; don't need help with how-to smtp in Python.

Does anyone know of documentation that describes these options and how to use them?

https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/smtplib.html

https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/email-examples.html#email-examples

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the SMTP server responds correctly to the 'EHLO' command then it supports ESMTP.

```
8BITMIME —8 bit data transmission, RFC 6152[1]

ATRN —Authenticated TURN for On-Demand Mail Relay, RFC 2645[2]

AUTH —Authenticated SMTP, RFC 4954[3]

CHUNKING —Chunking, RFC 3030[4]

DSN —Delivery status notification, RFC 3461[5]

ETRN —Extended version of remote message queue starting command TURN, RFC 
1985[6]
HELP —Supply helpful information, RFC 821[7]

PIPELINING —Command pipelining, RFC 2920[8]

SIZE —Message size declaration, RFC 1870[9]

STARTTLS —Transport layer security, RFC 3207 (2002)[10]
 - Not relevant in python3 as it is a separate function

SMTPUTF8 —Allow UTF-8 encoding in mailbox names and header fields, RFC 6531[11]
```

DSN Usage/Syntax Example:

```
smtp.send_message(msg, rcpt_options=['NOTIFY=SUCCESS,DELAY,FAILURE'])
```

Notes:

- ESMTP Specification states that DSN may be specified in any combination of character-case and any combination of options (success, delay, or failure).
- DSN functionality depends upon every email server from sender to recipient supporting it.

References:

- [1] https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6152
- [2] https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2645
- [3] https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4954
- [4] https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3030
- [5] https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3461
- [6] https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1985
- [7] https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc821
- [8] https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2920
- [9] https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1870
- [10] https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3207
- [11] https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6531
- https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/smtplib.html
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_SMTP